# Maven: How to write custom plugin to copy static resources?

Tags: ant, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

All our projects that are using docbook for creating documentation must have a set of static resources (images, css files and the like) in a particular target folder structure during site generation.

To assemble these resources and do the copying, I wanted to write a custom plugin that just has to be added in those projects, is bound to appropriate lifecycle phase and on execution copies all required files.

First approach was to create Ant based plugin, since the copy task is written down in a couple of lines. However, Ant's copy tasks copies what's in the filesystem... but on execution of the plugin the resources are in plugin's classpath and not available in filesystem. Right?

So I probably do have to write a MOJO (Java based). I guess **binary copying of resource files and folders from plugin's classpath to the project's target folder** is more or less a standard task, so what support do I get in developing the plugin? Are there any base or utility classes I should use, or any plugin I can copy some code from?

Comment: Have you read the docs of the maven-site plugin ? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html

Answer (score 0):

The [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html) exactly has already that kind of functionality. Take a deeper look into the docs.

Comment: Yeah, but I do not want to repeat the plugin configuration nor to include the resource files in each and every project. Instead, resources and the copy logic should be encapsulated in a plugin that just has to be included. Moreover, I'm not able to configure that in a parent POM since not all projects share same POM hierarchy.

Comment: Do i understand you correctly that you have resources which are used from multiple projects? If so than you should think about creating your own skin instead of using the maven-default-skin for the site creation.

Comment: We already have our own skin which is the same for all projects. The mentioned resources are actually not part of the site, but instead are used during site build to generate some documentation files (PDFs, for instance) -- which in turn are put into the site. That is, the resources are not part of the site themselves but are used to build documents, but only by some of our projects.

Comment: BTW, what I already tried is to put the resources into a separate Maven project (JAR) that is unpacked with maven-dependency-plugin in all related projects, but I rather want to do both (keep resources and copy them) in one single plugin...